# Rotating a grid of div's through center

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make a grid of div elements rotate around it's center. I googled and found out that transform-origin property can be used to anchor rotation. But somehow it's rotating with one of the corner as anchor. What I need to do to make it work and rotate around grid's center?

```js
var n = 20;

for( var i=0; i<n; ++i){
  for(var j =0; j<n; ++j)
    {
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        div.style.width = "9px";
        div.style.height = "9px";
        div.style.position = "absolute";
        div.style.left = i*10 + "px";
        div.style.top = j*10 + "px";
        div.style.background = "black";
        
        document.getElementById("top-div").appendChild(div);
      
    }
}

var d = 0;
setInterval( function(e) {
  d  = (d +  1)%360;
  document.getElementById("top-div").style.transform = "rotate("+ d  + "deg)";
}, 1);
```

```css
#top-div{
  transform-origin: center center;
  -ms-transform-origin: center center;
  -webkit-transform-origin: center center;
  -moz-transform-origin: center center;
  -o-transform-origin: center center;

}
```

```html
<div id='top-div'></div>
```

Using Google Chrome Version 57.0.2987.98 (64-bit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you didn't set a width and / or height to the rotating div; It needs a width and height to calculate where the anchor is.

```js
var n = 20;

for (var i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
  for (var j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.style.width = "9px";
    div.style.height = "9px";
    div.style.position = "absolute";
    div.style.left = i * 10 + "px";
    div.style.top = j * 10 + "px";
    div.style.background = "black";

    document.getElementById("top-div").appendChild(div);

  }
}

var d = 0;
setInterval(function(e) {
  d = (d + 1) % 360;
  document.getElementById("top-div").style.transform = "rotate(" + d + "deg)";
}, 1);
```

```css
#top-div {
  transform-origin: center center;
  -ms-transform-origin: center center;
  -webkit-transform-origin: center center;
  -moz-transform-origin: center center;
  -o-transform-origin: center center;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id='top-div'></div>
```

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, what are you going to use it for? Looks kinda trippy and I couldn't think of a purpose ;)

Comment: Just playing around for now. But after a long time practising this, I will be able to quickly create animations of what I study in mathematics and will help me enjoy problem solving more! and yes I will select it as correct answer as soon as it allows me to.

Comment: @antimercy: could you set this answer to accepted? (for Google purposes)

Comment: I am trying. It says wait for few minutes. :)